# Como ocultar a metabox dos "Campos Personalizados" do Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

criei implementei uma função no meu tema wordpress que salva a quantidade de vezes que um post foi visualizado, está funcionando como queria, porém quando vou editar o post esse campo personalizavél fica disponivél para ser alterado.

Meu objetivo é que não sejá possível ser alterado manualmente na edição do post:
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y3dQ.png)

Segue a função que salva no banco:

```
function setPostViews($postID)
{
    $countKey = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $countKey, true);
    if ($count == '') {
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $countKey);
        add_post_meta($postID, $countKey, '0');
    } else {
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $countKey, $count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ainda será possível manipular o valor através da requisição de criação ou edição do post, no entanto, visualmente, não será mais possível editar, a não ser que a pessoa modifique o css da página para exibir novamente o metabox

Esse snippet irá "esconder" com css essa box de edição dos postmeta:

```
// Adiciona um estilo css inline no head da wpadmin pra esconder o postmeta metabox
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_postmeta_metabox');
function hide_postmeta_metabox() {
    // Variavel global da administração que diz em que página estamos.
    global $pagenow;

    // Verifica se estamos na página de edição de post ou criação de um novo post para não conflitar com nada administração
    if ( $pagenow == 'post.php' || $pagenow == 'post-new.php' ) {
        echo '<style>
        .postbox#postcustom {
            display: none;
        }
        </style>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado JassRiver, com base no que informou eu consegui adaptar para o meu caso. Como não queria esconder todos os campos alterei o if para esconder apenas o campo que não queria que fosse exibido para o usuario.                                                               if ( $pagenow == 'post.php' || $pagenow == 'post-new.php' ) {
        echo '<style> 
        #postcustomstuff table tr#meta-560{
            display: none;
        }
        </style>';
    }